# sfdx.exe deploy approval process fails with "The approver null has an invalid type. Replace PreviousApprover with a valid enumeration value."

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, approval-process, sfdx-error

I am working with sfdx

Trying to deploy a changed approval process from my sandbox to production

I am getting the approval process with no problems with this command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApprovalProcess:myCustomObject__c.appProcessName
```

When I try to deploy with this command:

```
sfdx deploy -m ApprovalProcess:myCustomObject__c.appProcessName
```

I always get this error:

> The approver null has an invalid type. Replace PreviousApprover with a valid enumeration value.

Of course, the approver in Salesforce UI is filled and have a good and active user in it.

Now when I look into the approval process file, I see that there is a step that it's approver is of type `PreviousApprover` and without a name:

[image]

This is a very strange behaviour - I cannot find this in the Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm) and when I change the approver for this step in Saleforce UI and then run the sfdx retrieve command, this `PreviousApprover` does not change.

Other approval processes in my sandbox do not have this `PreviousApprover` and are deployed successfully.

Also cloning this component also clones the `PreviousApprover` and have the same problem

**My question is:**

Can I fix this approval process?

How can I get this component and deploy it without this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head for hours trying to fix this issue. It's still live as of 2024. I'm pretty sure it's a bug from Salesforce, and it occurs once you try to update the older Approval Processes.

To resolve that, find out this tag:

```
<type>PreviousApprover</type>
```

[image: Previous Approver]

And see which step of the approval process this is in. From the UI, check in that particular step what the queue/group is. Put that queue/group manually in the XML. This will resolve the issue.

[image: Steps]

In here, I updated the first portion to this:

```
   <approver>
        <type>PreviousApprover</type>
    </approver> **[Removed this portion]**

<approver>
    <name>Maria_Step</name>
    <type>queue</type>
</approver> **[added this portion]**
```